# Tell wget to only download the most recent file in a directory?

Tags: linux, ftp, wget, radolan

Is it possible to use wget to only download the latest file in a directory? I know it is possible to download only files that haven't been downloaded yet with the option -nc, but I only want the latest single file from ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/grids_germany/hourly/radolan/recent/ to be downloaded and not all (new) files in that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to download the latest file using its version number:

```
wget ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/grids_germany/hourly/radolan/recent/$(wget -O- ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/grids_germany/hourly/radolan/recent/ | egrep -o 'raa01-rw_10000-[0-9\.]+\-dwd---bin.gz' | sort | tail -1)
```

Comment: Warning: When I copied this from SO to my terminal, it added some escape characters which made the command not work. Your command is correct, but if someone runs into an error, that is likely why. Just remove the \'s before some brackets after copying and it should be good.